# Placing div outside of colorbox iframe and on top of colorbox-overlay

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Currently I'm trying to place a div outside of the colorbox and place it absolute somewhere in the colorbox overlay. The page I'm loading in a colorbox is a iframe, so I would like to place the div outside of the colorbox in which the iframe is loaded. I've tried this:

```
 #facebook-test { z-index: 9999; position: absolute; top: -20px; left: -20px; background:#000; height: 100px; width: 100px;}
```

the z-index of this div is higher then the z-index of the #colorbox and #colorbox-overlay.
But I can't seem to get it out of the iframe? Do I need to load a div when opening the colorbox?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try appending  it to the body by using:

```
$("body").append(<div id='#facebook-test'></div>);
```